# Go Mime package (1.14) behaves differently locally compared to the official Docker image

Tags: go, mime-types

I have upgraded my local Go version from `1.13` to `1.14` and then I updated a project I was working on via re-initializing using `go mod`.

Locally:

```
$ go version
go version go1.14 linux/amd64
```

`go.mod` of my project:

```
module example-project

go 1.14
```

There has been an update in the `mime` package in Go [1.14](https://golang.org/doc/go1.14#mime) that changes the default type of `.js` files from `application/javascript` to `text/javascript`.

I have an application that serves a folder with a JavaScript file in it like:

```golang
func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/static/", StaticHandler)

    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}

func StaticHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fs := http.StripPrefix("/static", http.FileServer(http.Dir("public/")))

    fs.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
```

I updated a test case to reflect the mime changes in Go 1.14:

```golang
func TestStaticHandlerServeJS(t *testing.T) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "/static/index.js", nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    rr := httptest.NewRecorder()
    handler := http.HandlerFunc(StaticHandler)

    handler.ServeHTTP(rr, req)

    if status := rr.Code; status != http.StatusOK {
        t.Errorf("handler returned wrong status code: got %v want %v",
            status, http.StatusOK)
    }

    expected := "text/javascript; charset=utf-8"
    if rr.Header().Get("Content-Type") != expected {
        t.Errorf("handler returned unexpected Content-Type: got %v want %v",
            rr.Header().Get("Content-Type"), expected)
    }
}
```

When I run this locally, the test case which checks the Content-Type fails:

```
TestStaticHandlerServeJS: main_test.go:27: handler returned unexpected Content-Type: got application/javascript want text/javascript; charset=utf-8
```

I can also confirm in the browser that the file is indeed served with the Mime Type "application/javascript" as it was back in Go 1.13.

When I run this test on a Docker container using the official `golang:1.14.0-alpine3.11` image, this test passes, and it reflects the changed behavior of the `mime` package.

So as a result, I'm left with a test case that fails locally and passes on the container. I maintain only a single version of Go locally, and that's `1.14` as I've shown above. What could be the reason why my local Go installation has the `mime` package behaving differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was interesting to me too and I have had the same behaviour like you - go 1.14 delivered on my mashine (macOs catalina) application/javascript instead of text/javascript. I debugged the program and found this function in type.go of mime package:

```
func initMime() {
    if fn := testInitMime; fn != nil {
        fn()
    } else {
        setMimeTypes(builtinTypesLower, builtinTypesLower)
        osInitMime()
    }
}
```

interesting stuff is going on in else block. After setting builtInTypes where extention `js` is assigned to `text/javascript` there is os specific assignment of file extention to content type, which overwrites the built-in assignment. On mac it is going to file type_unix.go where files

```
"/etc/mime.types",
"/etc/apache2/mime.types",
"/etc/apache/mime.types",
```

are tested to be available and in my case a file `/etc/apache2/mime.types` was present in the os and it contains ... surprise a line
**application/javascript                js**
and this line overwrites the go built-in definition for .js extention and results in `Content-Type: application/javascript` to be delivered to client and cause your test to fail.

Comment: had a tough time figuring out why `mime.TypeByExtension(".mp4")` was returning video/mp4 on my local machine, but not inside docker container. Thanks for pointing this out. https://github.com/rclone/rclone/issues/6384#issuecomment-1238063058 is a nice fix for folks using docker. Install mailcap to get these mime files